# Can't serialize/deserialize a list of objects from Javascript to C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, deserialization

I can currently serialize a single object in Javascript, post it via Ajax in Json and deserialize it in codebehind using a custom class as follows:

Javascript:

```
var ticket =
{
    "aNumber" : 1,
    "aString" : "foo"
};

jsonData = JSON.stringify(ticket);

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url_webservice + "action",
        data: "{obj:" + jsonData + "}",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

Custom class:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int aNumber { get; set; }
    public string aString { get; set; }
}
```

Codebehind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void action(Ticket obj)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

---

Now I want to accomplish the same but with several tickets as follows:

```
var tickets =
[
    {
        "aNumber" : 1,
        "aString" : "foo"
    },
    {
        "aNumber" : 2,
        "aString" : "bar"
    }
];
```

I tried to create a class by composition:

```
public class TicketsDTO
{
    LinkedList<Ticket> tickets;
}
```

And then by inheritance:

```
public class TicketsDTO : LinkedList<Ticket>
{
}
```

None seems to work. I did update the argument of the WebMethod accordingly

```
[WebMethod]
public static void action(TicketsDTO obj)
{
    console.log(""); //breakpoint
}
```

but the execution does not reach the breakpoint in these two cases and I don't get an error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried `action(List<Ticket> obj)`?

Comment: I haven't and it works. Thanks, you solved the most important part of the problem. I tried action(LinkedList<Ticket> obj) and it didn't work. Do you have any suggestions to make it work with LinkedList?

Comment: What of the features LinkedList have, which List doesn't? Why you need it?

Comment: It has the feature that my DAL is implemented with linked lists and I don't want to rewrite it.

Comment: You can always create `LinkedList` from deserialized `List`